# Understanding definition of Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning, riemann-integration

I have read this definition first time today. As far as I can understand it, it seems to me that difference between Riemann sums and a number L can be made small  by changing norm of partition. Does the changing norm of partition change values of $L$ and $\varepsilon$? $\delta$ is dependent on $\varepsilon$, HOW? What does it mean that the set of all Riemann integrable functions on $[a,b]$ is $\mathcal R[a,b]$?

Thanks for help

[image]

Comment: Why would not be $\delta$ dependent on $\varepsilon$? If you want to get closer to $L$ then you will have to make the partition finer. $L$ must not change. That is, the R integral of the function is $L$. The definition says that the Riemann integral exists if there exists such an $L$... The set of R integrable functions on $[a,b]$: this is just a notation for a set of certain functions.

Comment: @zoli yeah i can see that now.Thanks but how can we predict about L ? Do we always have to predict about L to use this definition ?

Comment: No, no. Smart people have worked out rules based on which you can mechanically calculate integrals. The theory behind makes sure that talking about the thing called Riemann integral is meaningful. There is another practical application of the definition: when you want to numerically integrate functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow carefully on the order of quantifications. The function is Reimann integrable if there exists a number $L$ (and it remains fixed!) such that for any $\varepsilon >0$ (which you are free to choose as you like, but once you made that choice it remains fixed) there exists a $\delta_\varepsilon >0$ (which may depend on $\varepsilon $ in any way whatsoever (and typically it does not matter at all how it depends on it)) such that for any partition with mesh less than $\delta_\varepsilon $, the corresponding Riemann sum is within distance $\varepsilon $ from $L$. Finally, $\mathcal R[a,b]$ is just the name given to the set of all Riemann integrable functions on $[a,b]$.

Comment: E may come before I in your name, but it's the other way around in Bernhard's :-)

Comment: @Ittay Weiss How can we say about or predict about L ?

Comment: Do you mean to say that with finer partitions we get close to L in better way ?

Comment: In general you can't say anything about $L$. That is what integration techniques are for. It is possible though to characterise the Riemann integrable functions on a closed interval, i.e., giving a condition that guarantees the existence of an appropriate $L$. A function is Riemann integrable if, and only if, its set of discontinuities is countable.

Comment: @Ittay Weiss okay so jist is by varying mesh we get different approximations and if we can choose a feasible combination of mesh and delta we are done .Is this it ?

Comment: I suggest you go back and first fully understand the notion of limit of a function at a point. If you understand that concept, then this notion of integrability won't be so hard.

Answer (score 1):

If your function is continuous on the interval $[a,b]$ it is also uniformly continuous:

$$\forall, \epsilon > 0 \; \exists \delta>0: |x-y|< \delta \; x,y \in [a,b]\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon $$

take the norm of your partitions($P_1,P_2$) to be less than $\delta$. Let $P_3$ refine both partitions $P_3 = P_1 \cup P_2$

$$S(f,P_1) - S(f,P_2) = \sum_{j=1}^N (f(x_{t_j})- f(y_{t_j}))(t_{j+1}-t_j) $$

Therefore 
\begin{align*}
|S(f,P_1) - S(f,P_2)| &= \sum_{j=1}^N |(f(x_{t_j})- f(y_{t_j}))|(t_{j+1}-t_j) \\
&\leq \sum_{j=1}^N \epsilon  (t_{j+1}-t_j) = \epsilon (b-a)
\end{align*}

So as you reduce the norm of your partition, the distance to the limit of your sum gets smaller (at least an upper bound to this distance).